# Extract a string value of a key into another key/value in nested json and insert onto sql db

Tags: python, mysql, json, list, dictionary

Extract data from a nested json file and insert to sql db. 
**From key details I want to get information below and insert onto sql db;**

sample of json file data and key/value as follows

```
{
  "response": {
   "client_log": {
      "data": [
        {
          "city": "LONDON",
          "login": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
          "state": "MC",
          "details": "Please find report below:\r\n\r\n------Report Information------\r\n\r\nEmail Id: user1@gmail.com\r\nServ Id: 1101ar12\r\nServ Num: 11111\r\nServ Details: Super-A\r\nState: LONDON\r\nCity: LONDON\r\n\r\n------Service Information------\r\n\r\nUser Name: John Clark\r\nMobile Number: 000111222\r\n\r\n------Reported Form------\r\n\r\nForm-1: zzzzz\r\nType: 111\r\n\r\nRemarks: Remarks 123.",
          "log_number": "1",
          "department": "Sales",
          "staff_id": "S123",
          "staff_name": "EricY",
          "timestamp": "2020-02-27 15:57:24"
        },
        {
          "city": "SINGAPORE",
          "login": "BBBBBBBBBBBBB",
          "state": "XX",
          "details": "Please find report below:\r\n\r\n------Report Information------\r\n\r\nEmail Id: user2@gmail.com\r\nServ Id: 903oa112\r\nServ Num: 12345\r\nServ Details: Super-B\r\nState: Sydney\r\nCity: Sydney\r\n\r\n------Service Information------\r\n\r\nUser Name: Peter\r\nMobile Number: 333444555\r\n\r\n------Reported Form------\r\n\r\nForm-2: xxxxxxxxxx\r\nType: 111\r\n\r\nRemarks: Remarks 890.",
          "log_number": "1",
          "department": "Eng",
          "staff_id": "S456",
          "staff_name": "YongG",
          "timestamp": "2020-02-27 15:57:24"
        }
      ],
      "query": "13"
    },
    "response_time": "0.723494",
    "transaction_id": "909122",
    "transaction_status": "OK",

  }
}
```

This is snippet code I use to extract the data and insert onto sql

```
myfile = 'sample.json'

with open(myfile, 'r') as f:
   mydata = json.load(f)


sql = "INSERT INTO `table1` (`city`, `login`, `state`, `details`, `log_number`, `department`, `staff_id`, `staff_name`, `timestamp`) VALUES ( %(city)s, %(login)s, %(state)s, %(details)s, %(log_number)s, %(department)s, %(staff_id)s, %(staff_name)s, %(timestamp)s )"
cursor.executemany( sql, mydata['response']['client_log']['data'])

db.commit()
db.close()
```

from the code above I'm able to get the data inclusive key details but the details value I got is presented and inserted on sql in 1 big chunk data (sql column details)... Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily parse the `str` associated with the `details` key using the `split()` and/or `find()` methods. Go line by line, and assume everything to the left of the `:` is the key, and everything to the right is the value.

For example:

```py
import json

myfile = 'sample.json'

with open(myfile, 'r') as f:
   mydata = json.load(f)

for entry in mydata['response']['client_log']['data']:
    parsed_details = {}
    for line in entry['details'].split('\r\n'):
        split = line.find(': ') # find() returns -1 if no match is found
        if split != -1:
            key = line[:split]
            value = line[split+2:] # 2 = len(': ')
            parsed_details[key] = value
    entry['parsed_details'] = parsed_details
```

or

```py
import json

myfile = 'sample.json'

with open(myfile, 'r') as f:
   mydata = json.load(f)

for entry in mydata['response']['client_log']['data']:
    parsed_details = {}
    for line in entry['details'].split('\r\n'):
        try:
            key, value = line.split(': ', maxsplit=1)
            parsed_details[key] = value
        except ValueError:
            # This error is only thrown when the line doesn't have ': ' in it, 
            # which means there aren't enough values to unpack. It is safe to pass.
            pass
    entry['parsed_details'] = parsed_details
```

The `dict` that is each item of the `mydata['response']['client_log']['data']` `list` now has a `parsed_details` key, whose value is a `dict` with key and values pairs extracted from the `details` key, as you can see in this output:

```
mydata
Out[2]: 
{'response': {'client_log': {'data': [{'city': 'LONDON',
     'login': 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAA',
     'state': 'MC',
     'details': 'Please find report below:\r\n\r\n------Report Information------\r\n\r\nEmail Id: user1@gmail.com\r\nServ Id: 1101ar12\r\nServ Num: 11111\r\nServ Details: Super-A\r\nState: LONDON\r\nCity: LONDON\r\n\r\n------Service Information------\r\n\r\nUser Name: John Clark\r\nMobile Number: 000111222\r\n\r\n------Reported Form------\r\n\r\nForm-1: zzzzz\r\nType: 111\r\n\r\nRemarks: Remarks 123.',
     'log_number': '1',
     'department': 'Sales',
     'staff_id': 'S123',
     'staff_name': 'EricY',
     'timestamp': '2020-02-27 15:57:24',
     'parsed_details': {'Email Id': 'user1@gmail.com',
      'Serv Id': '1101ar12',
      'Serv Num': '11111',
      'Serv Details': 'Super-A',
      'State': 'LONDON',
      'City': 'LONDON',
      'User Name': 'John Clark',
      'Mobile Number': '000111222',
      'Form-1': 'zzzzz',
      'Type': '111',
      'Remarks': 'Remarks 123.'}},
    {'city': 'SINGAPORE',
     'login': 'BBBBBBBBBBBBB',
     'state': 'XX',
     'details': 'Please find report below:\r\n\r\n------Report Information------\r\n\r\nEmail Id: user2@gmail.com\r\nServ Id: 903oa112\r\nServ Num: 12345\r\nServ Details: Super-B\r\nState: Sydney\r\nCity: Sydney\r\n\r\n------Service Information------\r\n\r\nUser Name: Peter\r\nMobile Number: 333444555\r\n\r\n------Reported Form------\r\n\r\nForm-2: xxxxxxxxxx\r\nType: 111\r\n\r\nRemarks: Remarks 890.',
     'log_number': '1',
     'department': 'Eng',
     'staff_id': 'S456',
     'staff_name': 'YongG',
     'timestamp': '2020-02-27 15:57:24',
     'parsed_details': {'Email Id': 'user2@gmail.com',
      'Serv Id': '903oa112',
      'Serv Num': '12345',
      'Serv Details': 'Super-B',
      'State': 'Sydney',
      'City': 'Sydney',
      'User Name': 'Peter',
      'Mobile Number': '333444555',
      'Form-2': 'xxxxxxxxxx',
      'Type': '111',
      'Remarks': 'Remarks 890.'}}],
   'query': '13'},
  'response_time': '0.723494',
  'transaction_id': '909122',
  'transaction_status': 'OK'}}
```

I'm not very familiar with SQL, so I can't help you with your last step of updating your database.

Comment: Hi sir. thanks..it looks as what I expected....I haven't test it.. but may i know from the code execution above how parsed_details can be added onto mydata?....originally mydata only got details and doesn't have parsed_details... I don't get that part...appreciate if you can show me...

Comment: No worries. The `parsed_details` `dict` is added to `mydata` on this line at the bottom of the `for` loop: `entry['parsed_details'] = parsed_details`. `entry`, on that line, is really one of the items in this list (which is a `dict`): `mydata['response']['client_log']['data']`. So modifying `entry` on the 1st iteration of the `for` loop is really modifying `mydata['response']['client_log']['data'][0]`. And, of course, Python takes care of all the memory management for you, so it's as simple as that.

Comment: If you didn't want those parse details in their own separate `dict` (accessed by the key `'parsed_details'`), you could add them directly to the main `dict` with all the other keys/values by replacing this line (`entry['parsed_details'] = parsed_details`) with: `entry.update(parsed_details)`.

Comment: Hi @GordonAitchJay ... is it possible to have the parsed_details key to hve underscore instead of space for example 'Serv Id' to 'Serv_Id'?

Comment: Hi...after line parsed_details[key] = value.....I add ---> parsed_details = { x.translate({32:'_'}) : y  
                for x, y in parsed_details.items()}

Comment: Looks good to me! You could do it on the last line, outside the inner-most `for` loop: replace this line (`entry['parsed_details'] = parsed_details`) with this: `entry['parsed_details'] = { x.translate({32:'_'}) : y for x, y in parsed_details.items()}`. Also, you could have used the `replace()` method, like so: `x.replace(' ', '_')`. The result is the same, of course.